# PHP: How to get rid of all <![CDATA[ and ]]> occurrences in a string?

Tags: php, replace, tags, cdata

I tried this as a test:

```
<?php
$crap = "<![CDATA[Hello, world!]]>";
$crap = str_replace(list("<![CDATA[", "]]>"), "", $crap);
echo $crap;
?>
```

But it returned this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ')' in /srv/www/htdocs/test.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `list` with `array`. [`list`](http://www.php.net/list) is used for making several variable attributions at the same time.

But you should not parse XML with `str_replace`. Consider the following valid file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
<![CDATA[&]]>
</root>
```

After your replacement, it becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
&
</root>
```

which is invalid XML.